# Prevent insertBefore duplicating content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move the entire content of the `.main-section-image` before the `.main-section .content .title`. But when I use my jQuery code, the content of all other divs is duplicated.

How I can use an if condition to prevent duplicated text from adding to the area?

```js
$('.main-section-image').insertBefore('.main-section .content .title');
```

```css
.duo-left {float: left;}
.duo-right {float: right;}
.main-section {width: 100%; float: left;}
.main-section .content {
 width: 65%;
}

.main-section .main-section-image {
    width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-section">
    <div class="content duo duo-right">
        <div class="title">
            <p><span class="red">TITLE</span> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Section description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-section-image duo-left">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="main-section">
    <div class="content duo duo-left">
        <div class="title">
            <p><span class="red">TITLE</span> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Section description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-section-image duo-right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting *all* `.main-section-image` elements before *all* `.content .title` elements.

Since you have multiple `.main-section` elements that each contain their own images and titles, multiple images are inserted before all the titles.

I suggest using jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to make the change *within each* `.main-section` separately.
Below, I'm using jQuery's [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context), which uses [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

I also add a button and `click` handler to perform the insert.
But that's just for demonstration, so feel free to remove that code.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {

  $('.main-section').each(function() {
    var $image = $('.main-section-image', this);
    var $target = $('.content .title', this);
    $image.insertBefore($target);
  });

});
```

```css
.duo-left {
  float: left;
}

.duo-right {
  float: right;
}

.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.main-section .content {
  width: 65%;
}

.main-section .main-section-image {
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">Make The Change</button>
<hr>

<div class="main-section">
  <div class="content duo duo-right">
    <div class="title">
      <p><span class="red">TITLE</span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Section description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section-image duo-left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50.png">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="main-section">
  <div class="content duo duo-left">
    <div class="title">
      <p><span class="red">TITLE</span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Section description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section-image duo-right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50.png">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

You asked about how to add a class after the change. You can use jQuery's [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).
Since `insertBefore` returns a jQuery object, you can chain `addClass` afterwards, like this:

```
$image.insertBefore($target).addClass('another-class');
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {

  $('.main-section').each(function() {
    var $image = $('.main-section-image', this);
    var $target = $('.content .title', this);
    $image.insertBefore($target).addClass('another-class');
  });

});
```

```css
.duo-left {
  float: left;
}

.duo-right {
  float: right;
}

.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.main-section .content {
  width: 65%;
}

.main-section .main-section-image {
  width: 35%;
}

.another-class {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">Make The Change</button>
<hr>

<div class="main-section">
  <div class="content duo duo-right">
    <div class="title">
      <p><span class="red">TITLE</span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Section description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section-image duo-left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50.png">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="main-section">
  <div class="content duo duo-left">
    <div class="title">
      <p><span class="red">TITLE</span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Section description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section-image duo-right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50.png">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, can you tell me please how I can use the each() function, sorry but I'm not so good in jquery :)

Comment: Please see my example above. jQuery's `each()` iterates through a set of selected elements. So you can perform your `insertBefore` on each `.main-section` separately.

Comment: one small thing, we can do something to check if that .main-section div exist in page?

Comment: If there is no `.main-section`, the code won't do anything. The selection will be empty and the `each()` function won't fire. But if you really want to check for main sections, you can use the [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property like this: `if ($('.main-section').length>0) { ... }`.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much again for your help

Comment: can you tell help me with one more thing please, we can add a new class to the main-section-image after move?

Comment: excellent, everything is work now like charm, thank you so much